# Constructability of $20$ degree angle

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, minimal-polynomials

I need help with the last step of the proof of why a $20$ degree angle is not constructible. I understand we try and trisect a $60$ degree angle.

We use the triple angle formula and get

$$
\cos(\theta) = 4\cos^3\left(\frac\theta3\right) - 3\cos\left(\frac\theta3\right)
$$

Let $\theta  = 60, \beta = 20$ and we get

$$
8\alpha^3 - 6\alpha - 1 = 0
$$

We use the rational root test and find that the only roots can be $\left\{\pm1,\pm1/2,\pm1/4,\pm1/8\right\}$, none of which statisfy the equation. Therefore it has no rational roots and is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Now the part I don't understand or rather I want to make sure I understand correctly is,

Since get $8\alpha^3 - 6\alpha - 1$ is irreducible,

$$
[F(\alpha):F] = \deg(m_a) = 3 = \deg(\alpha)
$$

Why does the degree of the minimal polynomial equal the degree of the field extension?

Then from this since $3 \neq 2^k$ for some $k$ its not constructible.

Comment: This is the core of basic Galois theory: for each pair of roots of the minimal polynomial (assume separability for now), there exists a field extension map which sends one root to the other. In other words, the automorphism group generated by the extension of the polynomial is the symmetric group (or the field extension is a splitting field, whichever characterization you like better). What does that tell you?

Comment: Can you please help me by explaining how you got $8\alpha^3 -6\alpha =1$ from first one, i.e. $cos(\theta)= 4cos^3(\frac{\theta}{3}) - 3cos(\frac{\theta}{3})$. The term $\alpha$ is not in the first. The multiplication of coefficients of $\frac{\theta}{3}$ by two is unclear. Also, how the $cos(\theta)$ term transformed to $1$ is unclear.

Comment: Note that $\cos(60^\circ)= \frac12$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take some field $K$ and $\alpha\in L$ where $L$ is some field containing $K$. Suppose that $\alpha$ is algebraic over $K$, i.e. there is some polynomial $f(X)\in K[X]$ such that $f(\alpha)=0$. We now consider the *minimal polynomial* $p:=\min_K(\alpha)$ which is a monic irreducible polynomial of **smallest** degree possible such that $p(\alpha)=0$.

We now consider the simple extension $K(\alpha)$. Recall that $[K(\alpha):K]=\dim_K K(\alpha)$. All elements of the subfield $K\subset K(\alpha)$ can be realised as scalar multiplies of $1$ and hence the only elements of interest for giving a $K$-basis are the powers of $\alpha$. Consider the family $1,\alpha,\dots,\alpha^i,\dots$; we know that there has to be some positive integer $n$ such that $\alpha^n$ can be expressed as $K$-linear combination of lower powers (say for $n\ge\deg p$ using that $p(\alpha)=0$).

Hence the dimension of $K(\alpha)$ as $K$-vector space is at most $\deg p$. Now, suppose that there is some $m<\deg p$ such that $\{1,\alpha,\dots,\alpha^{m-1}\}$ is already linearily dependent over $K$. In this case there has to be some non-trivial relation $a_m\alpha^{m-1}+\cdots+a_0=0$ which (after rescaling) gives a polynomial expression in $\alpha$ of strictly smaller degree than $p$ equal to $0$. But this cannot be by the minimality of $p$. Hence $K(\alpha)$ is *precisly* of degree $\deg p$ over $K$.